# Can I ask my website users for Facebook permissions later as they use the website instead of during the sign up process?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website and want to know if I need to ask for permission from my users to post to their Facebook profile when they sign up ... or can I do this down the line when they share something with their Facebook account?

Comment: You can ask for additional permissions at any time, you just have to call the Auth dialog with the according scope parameter again.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question...the permission is to auto post to Facebook. So if my users want to turn the setting off, is the best thing to do to create a setting for it in my own site?

Comment: You can check permissions a user did grant to your application by a Graph API call to /me/permissions